# How to change a comparison function of std::set?

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have a data structure like this:

```
std::set<A, F1> sa; //A is a custom structure and F1 is its comparison function.
```

Since the `sa` is exposed to many other users,so I cant change the variable name.
Now I need to add another comparison function such as `F2`, but I still point it with `sa`.
Is there a way to switch comparison functions without changing the name?
I have a solution but there's a problem, let's see the code first:

```
class SortedQ
{
public:
    virtual void insert(const Idle_Agent& ia) = 0;
    virtual bool erase(const std::string& name) = 0;
};
template <typename F>
class CustomSortedQ : public SortedQ
{
public:
    void insert(const Idle_Agent& ia)
    {
        ...
    }
    bool erase(const std::string& name)
    {
        ...
    }
private:
    std::set<Idle_Agent, F> aq;
};

std::shared_ptr<SortedQ> ssq;
if(...)
{
    ssq.reset(new CustomSortedQ<F1>())
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I need to traverse the `aq` with a shared pointer pointed to the base class. But in
the base class, I dont know how the exactly data structure looks like, so I cant define the virtual function exactly.

How do I do?

Comment: You could add an abstract iterator class inside `SortedQ` with virtual `operator*`, and then implement it within `CustomSortedQ`.

Comment: A `std::set` can only have one comparison function. Maybe you want to switch to a `std::vector`. You would have to manually take care of duplicates, but you could easily use `std::sort` on it to get different orders.

Comment: what do you need the second comparison for? The comparison function of a set determines how the elements are organized internally, so you cannot change it on the fly. A set with a different comparison function is a different set

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you want to change the comparison function to achieve what? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: note that the comparison function not only determines the order of the elements, but also what elements are considered equivalent. Hence after putting the same elements in two sets with different comparators, they might have completely different sizes

Comment: Changing a template parameter in a class template yields a different *class*. This is not something like a member which you can easily exchange. Plus, what is supposed to happen? `set` uses a red black tree - changing the comparator would require the tree to be build from scratch, the same as if you simply instantiate a new set with the other comparator and insert all elements of the old set.

Comment: It seems like you mention two separate problems: wanting the change the comparator function(a), and not knowing how to iterate the container from the base-class pointer(b). I don't see how the two are related. **a**: You can't do that dynamically as templates generate your classes at compile time. So different comparator == different class, as a few people have already mentioned. Providing help for **b** is for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to change the comparison function for a given set. 
Now what you can do is making a custom set class that has a vector as the container.

The insertion can be done using std::insert and std::upper_bound

Check for existing items can be done using std::binary_search as the vector is sorted

```
template<typename T>
class custom_set
{
public:

    custom_set(std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> predicate) 
        :   pred_(std::move(predicate)) {}

    bool contains_element(T& element)
    {
        return std::binary_search(container_.begin(), container_.end(), element);
    }

    void insert(T& element)
    {
        if (!contains_element(element))
        {
            container_.insert(
                std::upper_bound(container_.begin(), container_.end(), element, pred_),
                element);
        }
    }

    void insert(T&& element)
    {
        insert(element);
    }

    void set_predicate(std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> new_predicate)
    {
        pred_ = new_predicate;
        std::sort(container_.begin(), container_.end(), pred_);
    }

    void reserve(size_t new_capacity)
    {
        container_.reserve(new_capacity);
    }

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin()
    {
        return container_.begin();
    }

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end()
    {
        return container_.end();
    }

private:
    std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> pred_;
    std::vector<T> container_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    custom_set<int> set_([](const int& i1, const int& i2) {return i1 < i2; });

    set_.insert(1);
    set_.insert(2);
    set_.insert(3);
    set_.insert(4);
    set_.insert(2);
    set_.insert(8);
    set_.insert(6);

    for (auto& elem : set_)
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    set_.set_predicate([](const int& i1, const int& i2) {return i1 > i2; });

    for (auto& elem : set_)
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

To be honest, i think this code can be improved and is just a rough sketch.
A normal set is probably still faster.
There are sure improvements to this.

Comment: Does not appear to actually address the question being asked.

Comment: To be honest, this isn't a bad answer, even if it's _slightly_ off-piste. It provides a set interface with better backing storage _and_ the ability to do what was asked for.

Comment: See also [`boost::flat_set`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx)

Answer (score 4):

### You don't

If you were to change the order after inserting some elements, your program would have undefined behaviour. If you are lucky, it would crash trying to find or insert an element. If you are less lucky, it would fail to find elements that were present. If you were unlucky, demons would fly out of your nose. If you were very unlucky, demons would fly into your nose.

The ordering of elements is part of the set's *type*.

Comment: To be fair, I'd rather demons fly _out_ of my nose than into it, so it's not all bad. :)